# Event "Sliding" in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-event

I want set event when user touch and sliding right -> left: -> " I want set 'Next' event", and sliding left -> right: -> "I want set 'Previous' event". .. in Linerlayout 
Can you helps me!
Thanks so much

Comment: your quality of question is poor i think..

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in an app for Cupcake (1.5) using the [GestureDetector.OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html)'s onFling event. Using the results from that can tell you in what direction a user was dragging their finger when they did a quick swipe, but a slow sliding motion doesn't work very well. There are many other gestures supported via that interface, and I'm sure one will suit your needs nicely.

Luckily there is now also a ViewPager class that (I think) will do exactly what you want it to do. 
The Android Developer blog has [a great post about how to use it here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).